# Eclipse WindowBuilder Not Resizing Frame

Tags: eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

Here's the code migrated from Netbeans to Eclipse 4.3 and WindowBuilder

I can't resize the Frame from GUI and I don't really understand why it isn't possible, when I select the root Frame and drag the edges, the frame won't update at all.

Does it have anything to do with using a LayoutManager properly? As far as I could tell, WindowBuilder isn't accessing or editing the .form file generated by Netbeans

```
public class ExploreDBX extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ExploreDBX and runs the alteration function
     */
    public ExploreDBX() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jDBXDirList = new javax.swing.JList();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jDBXExploreDirFileList = new javax.swing.JList();
        jDBXExploreDirLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jDBXExploreDirFileLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jDBXExploreCurrentPathLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jDBXExploreCurrentPathTextField = new java.awt.TextField();
        jDBXUploadFiles = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jDBXDownloadFiles = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jDBXCreateNewDir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jDBXDeleteFolder = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton4.setText("jButton4");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Explore DBX");
        setResizable(false);

        jDBXDirList.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jDBXDirListMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jDBXDirList);

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jDBXExploreDirFileList);

        jDBXExploreDirLabel.setText("Directories");

        jDBXExploreDirFileLabel.setText("Files");

        jDBXExploreCurrentPathLabel.setText("Current Path");

        jDBXExploreCurrentPathTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jDBXExploreCurrentPathTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jDBXUploadFiles.setText("Upload");
        jDBXUploadFiles.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jDBXUploadFilesActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jDBXDownloadFiles.setText("Download");
        jDBXDownloadFiles.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jDBXDownloadFilesActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jDBXCreateNewDir.setText("New Folder");
        jDBXCreateNewDir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jDBXCreateNewDirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jDBXDeleteFolder.setText("Delete");
        jDBXDeleteFolder.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jDBXDeleteFolderActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jDBXUploadFiles)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jDBXDownloadFiles)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jDBXCreateNewDir)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jDBXDeleteFolder)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 222, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jDBXExploreDirLabel))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jDBXExploreDirFileLabel)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 231, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jDBXExploreCurrentPathLabel)
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addComponent(jDBXExploreCurrentPathTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jDBXExploreDirLabel)
                    .addComponent(jDBXExploreDirFileLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 160, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(jDBXExploreCurrentPathTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jDBXExploreCurrentPathLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jDBXUploadFiles)
                    .addComponent(jDBXDownloadFiles)
                    .addComponent(jDBXCreateNewDir)
                    .addComponent(jDBXDeleteFolder))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ExploreDBX().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jDBXCreateNewDir;
    private javax.swing.JButton jDBXDeleteFolder;
    private javax.swing.JList jDBXDirList;
    private javax.swing.JButton jDBXDownloadFiles;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jDBXExploreCurrentPathLabel;
    private java.awt.TextField jDBXExploreCurrentPathTextField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jDBXExploreDirFileLabel;
    private javax.swing.JList jDBXExploreDirFileList;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jDBXExploreDirLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jDBXUploadFiles;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

later edit # 1

created a new file, tested and resize works, i need to figure out what causes this problem and decide if I should redo the whole interface and maybe tidy it up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a call to setResizable(false) inside your initComponents Method.  Remove that and it will work.

WindowsBuilder does not use .form files at all.  Eclipse and Netbeans have different implementations of a GUI builder.

Comment: removed setResizable ... GUI behaves the same, also checked from Frame properties if resizable is set to true, it is, restarted IDE, it behaves the same, i need to mention that I can resize other components (JTextField and such without any problems)

Comment: also sidenote # i'm not really sure if Netbeans auto-generated core is compatible with what the Eclipse WindowBuilder is capable of doing, so should be replaced with manual definition of the entire structure the old fashion way or redo the whole interface from scratch?

Comment: @cristi_b When I remove the setResizable() the frame re-sizes as expected, and this is in eclipse.  Are you trying to make the components inside the frame re-size with the frame?  If so you need to use a layout that allows components to re-size.  Group layout will keep components static unless you specifically set them to grow.  Try setting them to grow vertically and horizontally.  |

Comment: I would place the two JLists inside their own panel, and place your buttons and text fields in another.  The buttons and fields can still use group layout but make the content pane BorderLayout.  Place the panel with the JLists in the Center, and the Buttons in the south.  Any extra space in a BorderLayout goes to the center components.

Comment: As for WindowsBuilder, it will ignore the .form files.  It will reverse engineer the code that was generated by netbeans and then you can use the GUIBuilder to modify it however you want.  The resulting code will not work with the Netbeans GUI builder, however, because netbeans relies on .form files.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by the `pack();` call at the end of the constructor. Remove it and resizing will work as expected.